# how to calculate weights in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do a simple math calculation on table that i have below,

```
  +-----------+---------+----------+-------+-------+
  | Cty_lst   | Cty_Rgn | Criteria | Total | Sntmt |
  +-----------+---------+----------+-------+-------+
  | ALL       | ALL     | ALL      |  3155 | ALL   |
  | Bangalore | ALL     | ALL      |   628 | ALL   |
  | Chennai   | ALL     | ALL      |   337 | ALL   |
  | Delhi     | ALL     | ALL      |   263 | ALL   |
  | Gurgaon   | ALL     | ALL      |   282 | ALL   |
  | Hyderabad | ALL     | ALL      |   406 | ALL   |
  | Mumbai    | ALL     | ALL      |   482 | ALL   |
  | Noida     | ALL     | ALL      |   235 | ALL   |
  | Pune      | ALL     | ALL      |   522 | ALL   |
  +-----------+---------+----------+-------+-------+
```

i am trying to calculate weight of each city that consititutes to all, something like the outcome table below, wt_calc is computed by  dividing city total/all total 
e.g. city bangalore wt is calculated by 628/3155 = 19.90. i tried many variations of below code

```
SELECT Cty_lst , cty_rgn,Criteria, total,Sntmt,
       (100*SUM(CASE WHEN Sntmt = 'all'  AND Cty_lst != 'all' THEN total END) 
       / 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Sntmt = 'all' AND Cty_lst = 'all'  THEN total END) 
       ) AS wt_calc
FROM citytable
GROUP BY Srvy_cty

  +-----------+---------+----------+-------+-------+---------+
  | Cty_lst   | Cty_Rgn | Criteria | Total | Sntmt | Wt_Calc |
  +-----------+---------+----------+-------+-------+---------+
  | ALL       | ALL     | ALL      |  3155 | ALL   | 100     |
  | Bangalore | ALL     | ALL      |   628 | ALL   | 19.90   |
  | Chennai   | ALL     | ALL      |   337 | ALL   | 10.68   |
  | Delhi     | ALL     | ALL      |   263 | ALL   | 8.34    |
  | Gurgaon   | ALL     | ALL      |   282 | ALL   | 8.94    |
  | Hyderabad | ALL     | ALL      |   406 | ALL   | 12.87   |
  | Mumbai    | ALL     | ALL      |   482 | ALL   | 15.28   |
  | Noida     | ALL     | ALL      |   235 | ALL   | 7.45    |
  | Pune      | ALL     | ALL      |   522 | ALL   | 16.55   |
  +-----------+---------+----------+-------+-------+---------+
```

Comment: Do you have total of all cities as one separate row in the table? That would be a strange table design.

Comment: Is there a row with the value of `Cty_lst = 'ALL'` or is that calculated?

Comment: And what is srvy_cty, you don't make reference to it in the select clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`Cty_lst` varchar(9), `Cty_Rgn` varchar(3), `Criteria` varchar(3), `Total` int, `Sntmt` varchar(3))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`Cty_lst`, `Cty_Rgn`, `Criteria`, `Total`, `Sntmt`)
VALUES
    ('ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', 3155, 'ALL'),
    ('Bangalore', 'ALL', 'ALL', 628, 'ALL'),
    ('Chennai', 'ALL', 'ALL', 337, 'ALL'),
    ('Delhi', 'ALL', 'ALL', 263, 'ALL'),
    ('Gurgaon', 'ALL', 'ALL', 282, 'ALL'),
    ('Hyderabad', 'ALL', 'ALL', 406, 'ALL'),
    ('Mumbai', 'ALL', 'ALL', 482, 'ALL'),
    ('Noida', 'ALL', 'ALL', 235, 'ALL'),
    ('Pune', 'ALL', 'ALL', 522, 'ALL')
;

select
t.*
, Total / @total * 100
from
Table1 t
, (select @total := (select Total from Table1 where Cty_lst = 'ALL' limit 1)) vars

|   CTY_LST | CTY_RGN | CRITERIA | TOTAL | SNTMT | TOTAL / @TOTAL * 100 |
|-----------|---------|----------|-------|-------|----------------------|
|       ALL |     ALL |      ALL |  3155 |   ALL |                  100 |
| Bangalore |     ALL |      ALL |   628 |   ALL |              19.9049 |
|   Chennai |     ALL |      ALL |   337 |   ALL |              10.6815 |
|     Delhi |     ALL |      ALL |   263 |   ALL |                8.336 |
|   Gurgaon |     ALL |      ALL |   282 |   ALL |               8.9382 |
| Hyderabad |     ALL |      ALL |   406 |   ALL |              12.8685 |
|    Mumbai |     ALL |      ALL |   482 |   ALL |              15.2773 |
|     Noida |     ALL |      ALL |   235 |   ALL |               7.4485 |
|      Pune |     ALL |      ALL |   522 |   ALL |              16.5452 |
```

- [<kbd>sqlfiddle</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/725e1c/5/0)

Answer (score 0):

Throw your row with the ALL Values away and then use:

```
SELECT Cty_lst , cty_rgn,Criteria, total,Sntmt, 
    Total/(SELECT SUM(Total) FROM citytable) AS wt_calc
FROM citytable
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27040f/7

Comment: tried the suggested code but did not get the expected results as all of the values return as 1

Comment: i checked on the fiddle and this is the [outcome] (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27040f/6) i get

Comment: oh - my fault - the url changes with every edit...the right one: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27040f/7

Answer (score 0):

If i  understand you correctly this should do it:

```
SELECT Cty_lst , cty_rgn,Criteria, total,Sntmt,
       (100* total) /
       (SELECT total FROM citytable WHERE  Sntmt = 'all' AND Cty_lst = 'all')
       ) AS wt_calc
FROM citytable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT 
      a.*,
     round((a.Total/SUM(b.Total))*100,2) as weight
FROM 
      citytable as a,
      citytable as b
WHERE
      b.CTY_LST != 'ALL'
GROUP BY
      a.CTY_LST;
```

demo at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cbc23/17

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't put the total of the cities in a row. If you want to keep that I would do something like the following:

```
SELECT Cty_lst , cty_rgn,Criteria, total,Sntmt,      
   (CASE when Sntmt = 'all'  AND Cty_lst != 'all' THEN total ELSE total / sum(total)
END) AS wt_calc
FROM citytable
GROUP BY Srvy_cty
```

But better would be to just drop the total row and do this:

```
SELECT Cty_lst , cty_rgn,Criteria, total,Sntmt,      
   total / sum(total) as wt_calc
FROM citytable
GROUP BY Srvy_cty
```