# Calculating Weights At multilevel criteria in a table

Tags: mysql

this is a follow up from my previous question 
Here's [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996899/how-to-calculate-weights-in-mysql/20997482?noredirect=1#20997482)

I am able to retrive weights at  single column level however when i tried to do the same at a group level i run it issues below is my code to achieve the same

```
  SELECT
  a.`Srvy_Cty`,
  a.`Total` AS num,
  -- sum(b.total) as gt, 
  b.total AS den ,
  (a.total /b.total)*100 AS Wt,
  a.`Sntmt`,
  a.score

  FROM Subctylst A
  JOIN  Subctylst b
  ON  A.srvy_cty = B.srvy_cty AND A.cty_rgn = B.cty_rgn 
  WHERE  a.sntmt = 'All' AND  B.score = 2000
  GROUP BY a.srvy_cty, a.cty_rgn, a.sntmt
```

Please find the data and query in [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eac5ed/5), kindly guide me in fixing this

Desired Outcome

```
  +-----------+-------------------------------+-------+-------+----------+----------+
  | Srvy_Cty  |            Cty_Rgn            | Total | Sntmt |  score   | dsrd O/c |
  +-----------+-------------------------------+-------+-------+----------+----------+
  | ALL       | ALL                           |  3677 | ALL   | 2000     |          |
  | Bangalore | ALL                           |   628 | ALL   | 2000     | 100      |
  | Bangalore | CBD AND off CBD -  Bangalore  |     7 | D     | \N       |          |
  | Bangalore | CBD AND off CBD -  Bangalore  |     4 | I     | \N       |          |
  | Bangalore | CBD AND off CBD -  Bangalore  |     5 | S     | \N       |          |
  | Bangalore | CBD AND off CBD -  Bangalore  |    16 | ALL   | 87.1094  | 2.55     |
  | Bangalore | East & South East Bangalore   |    91 | D     | \N       |          |
  | Bangalore | East & South East Bangalore   |    82 | I     | \N       |          |
  | Bangalore | East & South East Bangalore   |    18 | S     | \N       |          |
  | Bangalore | East & South East Bangalore   |   191 | ALL   | 95.732   | 30.41    |
  | Bangalore | North & North East Bangalore  |    58 | D     | \N       |          |
  | Bangalore | North & North East Bangalore  |    85 | I     | \N       |          |
  | Bangalore | North & North East Bangalore  |    19 | S     | \N       |          |
  | Bangalore | North & North East Bangalore  |   162 | ALL   | 114.7119 | 25.80    |
  | Bangalore | South Bangalore               |    77 | D     | \N       |          |
  | Bangalore | South Bangalore               |   105 | I     | \N       |          |
  | Bangalore | South Bangalore               |    24 | S     | \N       |          |
  | Bangalore | South Bangalore               |   206 | ALL   | 112.0087 | 32.80    |
  | Bangalore | West AND North West Bangalore |    25 | D     | \N       |          |
  | Bangalore | West AND North West Bangalore |    25 | I     | \N       |          |
  | Bangalore | West AND North West Bangalore |     3 | S     | \N       |          |
  | Bangalore | West AND North West Bangalore |    53 | ALL   | 100      | 8.44     |
  | Calcutta  | ALL                           |   522 | ALL   | 2000     | 100.00   |
  | Calcutta  | Central Pune                  |    20 | D     | \N       |          |
  | Calcutta  | Central Pune                  |    22 | I     | \N       |          |
  | Calcutta  | Central Pune                  |     6 | S     | \N       |          |
  | Calcutta  | Central Pune                  |    48 | ALL   | 103.6458 | 9.20     |
  | Calcutta  | East Pune                     |    62 | D     | \N       |          |
  | Calcutta  | East Pune                     |    64 | I     | \N       |          |
  | Calcutta  | East Pune                     |     8 | S     | \N       |          |
  | Calcutta  | East Pune                     |   134 | ALL   | 101.4034 | 25.67    |
  | Calcutta  | North Pune                    |    34 | D     | \N       |          |
  | Calcutta  | North Pune                    |    25 | I     | \N       |          |
  | Calcutta  | North Pune                    |    11 | S     | \N       |          |
  | Calcutta  | North Pune                    |    70 | ALL   | 89.1633  | 13.41    |
  | Calcutta  | South Pune                    |    30 | D     | \N       |          |
  | Calcutta  | South Pune                    |    17 | I     | \N       |          |
  | Calcutta  | South Pune                    |     5 | S     | \N       |          |
  | Calcutta  | South Pune                    |    52 | ALL   | 77.4038  | 9.96     |
  | Calcutta  | West Pune                     |   115 | D     | \N       |          |
  | Calcutta  | West Pune                     |    81 | I     | \N       |          |
  | Calcutta  | West Pune                     |    22 | S     | \N       |          |
  | Calcutta  | West Pune                     |   218 | ALL   | 85.9776  | 41.76    |
  | Chennai   | ALL                           |   337 | ALL   | 2000     |          |
  | Chennai   | Central Chennai               |    24 | D     | \N       |          |
  | Chennai   | Central Chennai               |    11 | I     | \N       |          |
  | Chennai   | Central Chennai               |     2 | S     | \N       |          |
  | Chennai   | Central Chennai               |    37 | ALL   | 66.7641  | 7.09     |
  | Chennai   | North Chennai                 |    11 | D     | \N       |          |
  | Chennai   | North Chennai                 |    17 | I     | \N       |          |
  | Chennai   | North Chennai                 |     2 | S     | \N       |          |
  | Chennai   | North Chennai                 |    30 | ALL   | 118.6667 | 5.75     |
  | Chennai   | South Chennai                 |   113 | D     | \N       |          |
  | Chennai   | South Chennai                 |   108 | I     | \N       |          |
  | Chennai   | South Chennai                 |    28 | S     | \N       |          |
  | Chennai   | South Chennai                 |   249 | ALL   | 98.2178  | 47.70    |
  | Chennai   | West Chennai                  |     7 | D     | \N       |          |
  | Chennai   | West Chennai                  |     8 | I     | \N       |          |
  | Chennai   | West Chennai                  |     6 | S     | \N       |          |
  | Chennai   | West Chennai                  |    21 | ALL   | 103.4014 | 4.02     |
  +-----------+-------------------------------+-------+-------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: What do you want your result set to look like?

Comment: apologies for not being clear, the table in the question has a column named dsrd O/c that is short for desired outcome and is not a part of the original table available in [Click here -> fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eac5ed/6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is your 2nd question in 2 days I am going to get on the cliche'd soapbox to help you write better queries.

1. Never use a GROUP BY unless there are aggregate functions (i.e., SUM, MAX, etc.) - which you are not using in the above example.
2. When you do use GROUP BY, get in the habit of using every field in the SELECT that is not part of an aggregate function.

Here's the solution.  [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eac5ed/23)

```
SELECT
    a.`Srvy_Cty`,
    a.`Cty_Rgn`,
    a.`Total`,
    a.`Sntmt`,
    a.score,
    ROUND(100.00 * a.`Total`/ b.`Total`, 2) as dsrd
FROM Subctylst AS a
LEFT JOIN Subctylst AS b
  ON a.`Srvy_Cty` = b.`Srvy_Cty`
    AND b.`Cty_Rgn` = 'All'
      AND a.score <> '\N'
ORDER BY a.`Srvy_Cty`, a.`Cty_Rgn`
```

*(This does not match your output exactly. If you don't want the dsrd for the first record (i.e., `ALL ALL` then put this clause in the JOIN: `AND a.Srvy_Cty <> 'ALL'` )*

Comment: thanks a ton for the solution Agrizzo, i am new to this environment and your pointers helps me a great deal in understanding the mechanics... appreciate you taking time to guiding me ... cheers :)